# How do you read newer HDD motors (DC/Brushless) into arduino? (like stepper motors)

Tags: arduino, brushless-dc-motor, dc, stepper-motor

We had a version of the [HDDJ](http://www.instructables.com/id/HDDJ%5FTurning%5Fan%5Fold%5Fhard%5Fdisk%5Fdrive%5Finto%5Fa%5Frotary/) working with an arduino reading an old stepper motor (with 4 wires), then sending serial data to processing, using a midi library, and midiox + midiyoke. Having trouble getting reliable forward/back speed data from the newer HDD's (2 or 3 wires), I think they are brushless DC motors? anyone had any experiance with this?

Cheers,
Al

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1251656637/7#7) page,
it has the Arduino version of the Instructable, a video, and a diagram of how to set it up.

Comment: Wow this is excellent! Nice write up, code, and breadboard layout in fritzing.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a brushless motor from a CD player for input.
The best info I found was [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/HDDJ_Turning_an_old_hard_disk_drive_into_a_rotary/) Instructable.

They show how to use an op-amp to make the signals readable.

Comment: Yeah, had old steppers going with the op-amp, but brushless seemed to give unreliable glitches compared to the stepper.

Comment: You need to make sure you are connecting directly to the leads of the motor and have cut any and all the other circuitry out of the way. The motor I used had a number of hall effect sensors and such mounted internally. I opened it up and just unsoldered them before attaching the motor to the op-amp circuit.